# Testing persisted entities within Phpunit

Tags: php, symfony, mocking, phpunit

I'd like to assert that a method creates and persists certain entities. The method's class has an instance of `EntityManagerInterface` injected into it.

Within my Phpunit test I can do:

```
    $mockEntityManager = $this->getMockBuilder(EntityManagerInterface::class)
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();
```

and then instantiate the class and execute the method. However how can I check what entities get persisted?

Ideally I would just be able to override `$mockEntityManager`'s `persist` method with some arbitrary closure, e.g. one which appends to some `$expectedPersistedEntities` array, then I can make assertions against this array. However it seems overriding methods with custom behaviour is not possible in PHP.

If it was only one object being persisted then I could do e.g.

```
        $mockEntityManager->expects(self::once())
            ->method('persist')
            ->with($expectedSyncedObject);
```

however I'm expecting multiple different objects to get persisted and would like to assert all of them do so.

Is this possible?

Comment: I think you are going the wrong way with this. Why would you want to test an external system? You should assume it's already been tested and trust that **it will** persist your entities. I can see two possibilities: 1) You are using a custom `EntityManagerInterface` (which I don't think is the case, and if it would, you would want to check they actually are persisted). 2) You really want to test your factories and check the entities' state (i.e. that they are valid and hold correct values). Is there any other use case I'm missing?

Comment: Just to cover my bases: Look into `exactly` and `withConsecutive` in the [phpunit documentation](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/test-doubles.html#test-doubles-mock-objects-examples-with-consecutive-php).

Answer (score 0):

You can check every instance being persisted using `withConsecutive` [see the doc](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/test-doubles.html#test-doubles-mock-objects-examples-with-consecutive-php)